# formatting long division for integers

Tags: education

How do i fix this code to format long division correctly.

```
longDivision[x_Integer?Positive,y_Integer?Positive]:=Module[{
    yLength=IntegerLength[y],
    newnumber,quotient,
    remainder=0,
    list,pad=IntegerLength[x]
},
    list=IntegerDigits[Flatten[(
        newnumber=FromDigits[{remainder,#}];
        {quotient,remainder}=QuotientRemainder[newnumber,y];
        {newnumber,quotient*y}
    )&/@IntegerDigits[x]/.{_,0}->Nothing][[2;;]]];

    TextGrid[
        ReplacePart[
            PadLeft[
                Append[
                    {
                        {"","",Sequence@@IntegerDigits@Quotient[x,y]},
                        {y,"",Sequence@@IntegerDigits[x]}
                    }~Join~Table[
                        If[Mod[k,2]==1,{"-",Sequence@@#},Identity@#]&@ArrayPad[
                            list[[k]],
                            {0,Print[pad];If[IntegerDigits[Quotient[x,y]][[1+Ceiling[k/2]]]==0,pad=pad-2,--pad]},
                            ""
                        ]
                    ,{k,1,Length[list]}],
                    {remainder}
                ],
                Automatic,
                ""
            ],
            {}
        ],
        Alignment->{Right,Baseline},
        Dividers->{{2->True},{{{False,True}},2->True}}
    ]
];
```

So running the following should format correctly.

longDivision[324, 3]

longDivision[476, 3]

etc

Comment: What are you trying to reproduce - the division algorithm?

Comment: Yes i want to teach some kids how division algorithm works. I want it to be formatted so they can play with it and understand the way it is taught traditionally.

Comment: What tradition? Give an example or link.

Comment: Like shown here for integers.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LongDivision.html

Comment: @AlexTrounev any idea how to do this?

Comment: I will try to reproduce the algorithm from the Eric W. Weisstein page.  There is already code, but using `Print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a couple of corrections in the original code from [Eric W. Weisstein page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LongDivision.html). For children, it will fit.

```
LongDivide[x_, y_] := Module[
  {q, m, X, Y, Q, P, R, width},
  q = Quotient[x, y];
  m = Mod[x, y];
  {X, Y, Q} = Map[IntegerDigits, {x, y, q}];
  P = Reverse[y Q];
  R = Rest @ Reverse @ Prepend[
        FoldList[Floor[#2 + #1 /10] &, m + First @ P, Rest @ P],
        m
      ];
  width = 3 + Plus @@ Map[Length, {X, Y}];

  Print @ RightJustify[ToString @ q, width];
  Print @ StringJoin[
        Table[" ", {2 + Length @ Y}], 
        Table["_", {1 + Length @ X}]];
  Print @ StringJoin[ToString @ y, " | ", ToString @ x];
  Map[
    LongDivideAux[X, Y, Q, width, #] &, 
        Transpose @ {y Q, R, Range @ Length @ R}
   ];]

LongDivideAux[X_, Y_, Q_, width_, {yq_, r_, n_}] := 
 Module[{}, 
  Print@RightJustify[
    RightIndent[
     RightJustify[ToString@-yq, width], {Length@Q - n + 1}], width];
  Print@RightJustify[
    RightIndent[
     RightJustify[StringJoin@Table["_", {1 + Length@Y}], 
      width], {Length@Q - n + 1}], width];
  Print@RightJustify[
    RightIndent[RightJustify[ToString@r, width], {Length@Q - n}], 
    width];]
```

[image: fig1]